# Is it possible to count the number of reactions with on_message, and pin the message if it has 2 reactions?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(927625164038996019)
    if message.channel == channel:
        if message.author.id == 927033032882405517:
            pass
        else:
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
            await message.add_reaction("❌")
    else:
        pass
```

I would like to add:

```
if message.reactions == 2 await message.pin()
```

but it is not working, and every way I tried, it did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `on_message` it will be called once the message sent and it will not called for reacting the message with emoji. To tackle this issue you can use `on_raw_reaction_add` which will be called upon reacting the message with emoji. 
**Use the below code to solve this problem**

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  channel=await client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
  message=await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
  user = await message.reactions[0].users().flatten()
  if len(user)==2:
    await message.pin()
```

Comment: If this code solves your problem consider verifying my answer with green tickmark